# How to tell someone to "experience it to the maximum"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, vocabulary, phrases

What is the most natural way to say something like "put your senses on the maximum level"? Could I say:

> a) **Breath it in** with all of your senses?
>
> b) **Pull it in** with all of your senses?

Comment: Let's imagine a situation, You gave some flowers to your girlfriend. You chose the best flowers with beautiful fragrance. Then you said ' Take a deep sensation of these flowers'.  Does it make any sense? @Probable

Comment: @faisalamir Haha, not really. In Czech, we use something like the phrases a) and b) only when we talk about an experience. For instance, someone might dislike opera because "it's just a theater with people yowling". Someone might oppose them, saying it's about experiencing everything from the formality of it to the strength and focus necessary to perform an aria. In this context something like "You need to focus your senses" might express it's a holistic experience that requires an active apporach.

Comment: Ok..Hope that some well known people will give you the appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither one of those works. “Breath” (which should actually be “breathe”) doesn’t work here because you can’t breathe through all your senses - can you breathe through your hearing or your sense of touch? No, you can’t.

“Pull” doesn’t really work either because your senses don’t pull anything in - they react to things that are already there.

Some better options would be:

*Take* it in with all your senses.

*Savor* it with all your senses.

*Experience* it with all your senses.